# How do I correct this undefined method for main_image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I was trying to build out the show functionality in Rails in the portfolios_controller.rb:

```
class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
    def index
        # this calls the model
        @portfolio_items = Portfolio.all
    end

    def new
        @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new
    end

    def create
        @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new(params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body))

        respond_to do |format|
            if @portfolio_item.save
                format.html {redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Your portfolio item is now live'}
            else
                format.html {render :new}
            end
        end
    end

    def edit
        # its looking in the params in URI
        @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.update(params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body))
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'The record was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end

    def show
        @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])   
    end
    end
end
```

I created the show method inside the above controller and it needs to be able to find the portfolio item that it needs to use and pass it to a show file and render it to a link.

I didn't leave the show method blank because I do need to know what portfolio I am talking about. I know you see a lot of DRY, but eventually I am going to put it all in a before_action.

I created an show.html.erb in views folder:

```
<%= image_tag @portfolio_item.main_image %>
<h1><%= @portfolio_item.title %></h1>
<em><%= @portfolio_item.subtitle %></em>
<p><%= @portfolio_item.body %></p>
```

But I got this error:

[image]

When in the show page I do this:

```
<%= @portfolio_item.inspect %>
```

I get nil in the browser, yet in my rails console I have plenty of data:

```
2.3.3 :002 > Portfolio.all
  Portfolio Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "portfolios".* FROM "portfolios" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Portfolio id: 2, title: "Portfolio title: 1", subtitle: "My great service", body: "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette. \n\t\tSucculent...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05">, #<Portfolio id: 3, title: "Portfolio title: 2", subtitle: "My great service", body: "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette. \n\t\tSucculent...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05">, #<Portfolio id: 4, title: "Portfolio title: 3", subtitle: "My great service", body: "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette. \n\t\tSucculent...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05">, #<Portfolio id: 6, title: "Portfolio title: 5", subtitle: "My great service", body: "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette. \n\t\tSucculent...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05">, #<Portfolio id: 7, title: "Portfolio title: 6", subtitle: "My great service", body: "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette. \n\t\tSucculent...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05">, #<Portfolio id: 8, title: "Portfolio title: 7", subtitle: "My great service", body: "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette. \n\t\tSucculent...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05">, #<Portfolio id: 9, title: "Portfolio title: 8", subtitle: "My great service", body: "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette. \n\t\tSucculent...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05">, #<Portfolio id: 5, title: "Portfolio title: 5", subtitle: "My great service edited", body: "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette. \r\n\t\tSucculen...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 18:01:58">, #<Portfolio id: 1, title: "Portfolio title: 0", subtitle: "My great service", body: "Our seeds file uses the block system. The id start...", main_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/600x400", thumb_image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x200", created_at: "2017-06-06 02:14:05", updated_at: "2017-06-06 18:15:31">]>
```

If you look at my schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170605121642) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "portfolios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "subtitle"
    t.text "body"
    t.text "main_image"
    t.text "thumb_image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "skills", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "percent_utilized"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

You see that main_image is in the portfolios table. So I am unclear as to why I am getting this error.

This is the code for portfolios/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Portfolio Items</h1>

<%= link_to "Create New Item", new_portfolio_path %>

<% @portfolio_items.each do |portfolio_item| %>
    <p><%= link_to portfolio_item.title, portfolio_path(portfolio_item) %></p>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.subtitle %></p>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.body %></p>
    <!-- image_tag is a method to render an image -->
    <!-- Run this code unless portfolio_item.thumb_image is nil -->
    <%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image unless portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_portfolio_path(portfolio_item) %>
<% end %>
```

This is my rake routes | grep portfolios:

```
danales-MacBook-Pro:dancortesPortfolio danale$ rake routes | grep portfolios
    portfolios GET    /portfolios(.:format)          portfolios#index
               POST   /portfolios(.:format)          portfolios#create
 new_portfolio GET    /portfolios/new(.:format)      portfolios#new
edit_portfolio GET    /portfolios/:id/edit(.:format) portfolios#edit
     portfolio GET    /portfolios/:id(.:format)      portfolios#show
               PATCH  /portfolios/:id(.:format)      portfolios#update
               PUT    /portfolios/:id(.:format)      portfolios#update
               DELETE /portfolios/:id(.:format)      portfolios#destroy
```

Comment: Are you passing the param `id`?

Comment: So the route has the id in it correct?  Something like " /portfolio_item/2 " or what ever the name of the route is with the id after it?

Comment: I assume you get the error after cliciking some link (most likely in `index.html.erb`), if so, could you provide the code of that link?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma, are you asking if I am passing the params[:id] in the controller? If so, then yes. Gerry, yes I get it when I click on the link in the show page. That page is supposed to show me details. You are correct, it is index.html.erb. I will paste it now.

Comment: And how does your routes look like?

Comment: I added the routes @Md.FarhanMemon.

Comment: Is your controller which you shared is complete? I see there's an extra `end` a typo or are there any methods or callbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this is the exact error..you have written your `show` action inside `update`

```
def update
  @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @portfolio_item.update(params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body))
      format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'The record was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
def show
  @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Farhan, I would give you 30 upvotes if I could. Thank you. Attention to detail is a must have skill requiring daily sharpening in this game. Thank you again.

Comment: Proper indentation helps too.. :)